# Why my process became T （Terminated）State ？

Tags: java, linux, process

A simple Java demo

```
public class Test {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    int number = scanner.nextInt();
    System.out.println(number);
  }
}
```

I compiled the program and run it background : `java Test &`, but the process was Terminated State and stopped, I just know the reason is related about `scanner.nextInt()` function, but I don't understand the details.

Comment: You running `jar` file ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"T" state is "stopped", not "terminated".

Your process is being stopped because it tried to read from the terminal while in the background. Bring it to the foreground to send it input.